# What access requires to put files in IE temp folder

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, permissions, caspol

My web application is in .net framework 2.0.I want to put some files in client's Internet Temp Folder for some process. How I will set right to application as full trust so that application can easily place files in IE's temp folder. Can I use CASPOL.EXE to set or do I have set some setting in applications web.config file.

Thanks in advance.